# I am getting the error code CS0411

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What does the following error message mean?

> Error CS0411
>   The type arguments for method
>   'Component.GetComponent()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments explicitly

This is my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private float speed;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent();
        rb.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't tell the method what kind of component to get. How is it supposed to deduce that information? You need to explicitly tell it to get the RigidBody attached to your GameObject. [Please review the documentation more closely on how to do this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html).

Answer (score 5):

Problem here

```
rb = GetComponent();
```

Fix is

```
rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
```